# How to set font for y-axis iOS Charts

Tags: ios, fonts, ios-charts

I know that I am able to set the font of the x-axis in iOS Charts using the following code:

```
myChart.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont.init(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 10)!
```

So, I thought that I would be able to change the font of the y-axis using similar code such as:

```
myChart.getAxis(.Right).labelFont = UIFont.init(name: "AvenirNext-Heavy", size: 10)!
```

However, the following code doesn't do anything. Is it possible to change the font of the y-axis? I tried to run the app and there was no change in the font.

Comment: it should work. If you think it's a bug, report it on github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work on y axis too, I checked the func, and it is reading labelFont already (If you think it's a bug, report it on github):

```
/// draws the y-labels on the specified x-position
internal func drawYLabels(context context: CGContext, fixedPosition: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat, textAlign: NSTextAlignment)
{
    guard let yAxis = yAxis else { return }

    let labelFont = yAxis.labelFont
    let labelTextColor = yAxis.labelTextColor
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, just wonder why the font won't change... Maybe a bug? I might submit a bug report

Comment: I suggest play with ChartsDemo to see if you can reproduce, if so, fire an issue on github

Comment: Ok  I will play around with it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code to set font for Left Axis (Y - left), the same with Right Axis:

```
   myChartView.leftAxis.labelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
    myChartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = .orange
```

Comment: please look at [answer]